# Setting heap size through WebLogic console in Server start arguments does not reflect the heap size

Tags: java, weblogic12c, jvm-arguments

I have set heap size in the WebLogic console server start JVM arguments as `-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m`. But at `setDomainEnv.sh` level it is `-Xms256m -Xmx512m`.

When I am starting the managed server, the heap size allocation is according to the `setDomainEnv.sh` and not according to my args. Can you explain how setDomainEnv takes precedence over the args and what should I do to start the JVM with the heap size mentioned in the server start arguments?

I have tried putting it in `startManagedWeblogic.sh` file and making StartScriptEnabled at `nodemanger=false` too. But nothing worked out.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You could improve your question by making it more readable by introducing paragraphs and formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just edit the values inside `setDomainEnv`. The name stands for "set domain environment", so that's where your environment configuration settings should be. You can even find such a suggestion in the Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40518_01/server.761/es_install/src/tins_postinstall_jvm_heap.html

> **Customizing the WebLogic JVM heap size**
>
> You can change the default JVM heap size to fit the needs of your deployment.
>
> The default JVM heap size for WebLogic is 3GB. The size is set in the setDomainEnv.sh file for Linux or setDomainEnv.cmd for Windows, which is in the $DOMAIN_HOME/bin directory. The heap size is set with the -Xmx option.

Comment: Thank you Alin for your suggestion. But once a guy from Oracle showed me that we can set it in server start arguments too. And the changes were reflecting. But somehow it is not working for me now. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: According to [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/weblogic_server_performance_and_tuning), setting the arguments in the Admin Console `is enabled ONLY if managed server is started via nodemanage/Admin Console and StartScriptEnabled is set to false in the nodemanager.properties which is default`

Answer (score 0):

You can add these two lines by editing `setDomainEnv.sh` just after the line that contains `# --- End Functions ---`

```
USER_MEM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
export USER_MEM_ARGS
```

Save the file and restart the WebLogic Server.